# ANYLOGIC- Automatically model creation

Tags: anylogic

Can anylogic automatically model if we provide the initial data to it in form of excel file or database so that it can  be populated with blocks like delay, resource pool, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but it is not for beginners. I recently had a full webinar about it, see https://youtu.be/casVdmKC-S0